# Can the Bayes Theorem be interpreted as a master equation in detailed balance?

Tags: stochastic-processes, bayes-theorem, stochastic-differential-equations

The general Bayes' theorem is well known as:

$$P(X|Y) = \frac{P(Y|X) \cdot P(X)}{P(Y)} $$

where $P(X)$ a prior probability distribution (*belief*), and $P(Y)$ a data probability distribution (*observation*).

If we would write:

$$ P(X|Y)\cdot P(Y) = P(Y|X) \cdot P(X) $$

and interpret the conditional probabilities as transition probabilities in the context of *master equations* (first order Markov chains assumed) then:

$$ 0= w(Y|X) \cdot P(X) - w(X|Y)\cdot P(Y)$$

Looks like a typical master equation under the very condition of *detailed balance*, derived from:

$$\partial_tP(X) = w(Y|X) \cdot P(X) - w(X|Y)\cdot P(Y)$$

> Question: Is this interpretation mathematically correct, namely to interpret the Bayes theorem as a stationary solution of a master equation in detailed balance? If its is correct, then please describe the corresponding Markov process; if it is not correct, then please explain why?

Comment: Interesting interpretation. One remark: in Bayes' theorem the prior and the the data are not "symmetric", that is, $P(Y|X)$ has a very different standing than $P(X|Y)$, whereas in detailed balance, the transitions are between 2 different states that are not special wrt to each other.

Comment: Just to check that I understood it correctly: given a probability measure $\mathbb P$ on some measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$, you want to know whether there is some Markov process on the state space $\mathcal F$ such that $P$ is the associated stationary measure?

Answer (score 0):

I could meanwhile answer this question and like to reference the following article with a complete solution presented to this question;
https://medium.com/@vaseghisam/1763-meets-1968-how-bayes-illumes-the-detailed-balance-in-chapman-and-kolmogorovs-equation-7fc48e68140a